# Structure of the space $X:=\{x \subset \mathbb{R}^3: |x| < \infty\}$, where $|x|$ is the cardinality of $x$

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, lebesgue-measure

I am interested in the space 
$$
X:=\{x \subset \mathbb{R}^3: |x| < \infty\},
$$
where $|x|$ is the cardinality of the subset $x$. This is basically configuration space for a quantum system with a variable number of indistinguishable particle. In particular, I would like to define a metric (derived from the usual metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$), to know if the space is complete with respect to this metric, and to define a measure (derived from the usual Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Answer to Daniel Rust. My basic idea is the following: define $\Gamma:=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{R}^{3n}$, and then define $h:\Gamma \to X$ as follows: $h({\bf y}_1, \ldots, {\bf y}_n):=\{{\bf y}_1\} \cup \ldots \cup \{{\bf y}_n\}$. After this, for $y, y' \in \Gamma$, let $y \sim y'$ if $h(y)=h(y')$. There is an obvious bijection between $X$ and $\Gamma/\sim$, so one can define a suitable metric and a measure on $\Gamma/\sim$, based on the Euclidean metric and the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I assume the metric you'd use would be the Hausdorff metric? (The Hausdorff metric is defined by $\displaystyle{d(A,B)=\max\{\sup_{a\in A}\inf_{b\in B} d(a,b),\sup_{b\in B} \inf_{a\in A} d(a,b)\}\}}$ ).

Comment: I answered you in the main section

Comment: You can define a bunch of metrics on this space  by identifying each element of $X$ with a discrete probability measure on $\mathbb R^3$ and using some of the known [metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Dual_representation_of_W1) on the space of probability measures. I can't think of any natural metric that would be complete. I can't think of any natural measure at all.